# get OFFSET, LIMIT on query set

Tags: python, django

Do query set

```
    shops = Shop.objects.filter(
    id__in=list(set(shop_ids)))
if kitchens:
    shops = shops.filter(
        cuisineshop__in=kitchens)
if min:
    shops = shops.filter(
        delivery_price__gte=min)
if max:
    shops = shops.filter(
        delivery_price__lte=max)
if sort_type == 1:
    shops = shops.order_by('rate')
if sort_type == 3:
    shops = shops.order_by('rate')
if sort_type == 4:
    shops = shops.order_by('rate')

shops = shops.annotate(count=Count('name'))

shops = shops.all()[of:per_page]

print(shops.query)
```

There is `shops = shops.all()[of:per_page]`  `of = 5`, `per_page = 5`

but query return

```
    SELECT `catalog_shop`.`id`, `catalog_shop`.`name`, `catalog_shop`.`time_begin`, `catalog_shop`.`time_end`, `catalog_shop`.`phone`, `catalog_shop`.`preview`, `catalog_shop`.`delivery_price`, `catalog_shop`.`min_order`, `catalog_shop`.`del_wait_time`, `catalog_shop`.`is_always`, `catalog_shop`.`is_cash`, `catalog_shop`.`is_card`, `catalog_shop`.`is_online`, `catalog_shop`.`is_points`, `catalog_shop`.`notification`, `catalog_shop`.`email`, `catalog_shop`.`rate`, `catalog_shop`.`destination`, `catalog_shop`.`description`, `catalog_shop`.`cook`, `catalog_shop`.`image_cook`, `catalog_shop`.`desc_cook`, `catalog_shop`.`shoptype_id`, `catalog_shop`.`slider_id`, COUNT(`catalog_shop`.`name`) AS `count` FROM `catalog_shop` WHERE (`catalog_shop`.`id` IN (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) AND `catalog_shop`.`delivery_price` <= 10000) GROUP BY `catalog_shop`.`id` ORDER BY `catalog_shop`.`rate` ASC LIMIT 5
```

can't understand why dosen't work offest wityh limit where  LIMIT(5,5)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[limiting-querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

what you probably want is following

```
 shops = shops.all()[5:10]
```

In your case

```
shops = shops.all()[of:of+per_page]
```